# Can we represent data structures (involving bit fields) in a language independent way?

Tags: bit-fields, bson, data-interchange

We have a dozen simulators talking to each other on UDP. The interface definition is managed in a database. The simulators are written using different languages; mostly C++, some in Java and C#. Currently, when systems engineer makes changes in the interface definition database, simulator developers manually update the communication data structures in their code. Messages are mostly 2-5 bytes long with bit fields for each signal. What I want to do is to generate one file from interface definition database describing byte and bit field definitions and let each developer add it to his simulator code with minimal fuss.

[edit] After Barmar's answer I've removed JSON/BSON from title.

Thanks

Zubair

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a high level data representation, it's only concerned with transmitting values, not the way they're represented in memory. And the J stands for `Javascript` -- it only deals with Javascript data types, which doesn't include bit fields (in fact, JSON is just a subset of the syntax for Javascript literals).